# How to read and insert correct highchart number in selectors using Selenium Webdriver with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, highcharts

I am testing a web application that uses highcharts. The selectors look like this, and the highchart number of the same chart is always different.

```
#highcharts-3 >div:nth-child(1) > span > div > span
```

How can I get the right highchart number of the chart I am on and then insert that number it in my selectors?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "right highchart number"? Do you mean the `3` in `#highcharts-3`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. The application has many highcharts. So that highchart number is always different for the same chart, and it appears to depend on how many other charts you clicked on before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to "extract" the number, instead you can use the [CSS3 [attribute^=value] Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp):

```
[id^='highcharts-'] > div:nth-child(1) > span > div > span
```

This will select the first element where the `id` begins with the string `'highcharts-'`.

Comment: Nice. I was doing it through looking for the highchart number in the page source via `html = browser.page_source` and then inserting the number in selectors, but your method is much neater. Thanks a lot!